# Usage of Articles in Grammar

Tags: articles

Can we use the Article "The" with "Aravali".
Aravali is a mountain range. As per grammatical rule, We can use "The" with name of "Ranges of Mountains". But, My book says that We can't use "The" with 'Aravali'.

Comment: The Aravali mountain range. There is only one.  Your book is wrong.

Comment: If you read the Wikipedia article titled [Aravalli Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aravalli_Range) you'll see that about half the 80-odd instances of ***Aravalli*** are preceded by ***the***. Personally, I think many of the instances there that *don't* include the article look a bit "strange", but it's not really something that even the most dedicated pedant could feel that strongly about. So for my money, the question is POB.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "POB"? If this is an expression for polite company, could you remind me what it stands for?

Comment: @LorelC: Sorry, I was getting a bit lazy (I usually write it out in full). **Primarily Opinion-Based**. There are no absolute "rules" governing which of two possibilities that are *both commonly used* is "correct" when it comes to proper nouns. And in this context, the fact that even the relevant Wikipedia article has 36 references without the article, and 43 *with* the article makes it a bit of a pointless question.

Answer (score 0):

Names are not preceded by articles in English.

> James is my brother.

However, a name may simply be part of a multi-word noun phrase.  If the name is not the complete noun phrase, the article can be used.

> The James River is polluted.

An article is not strictly required, though.  Not using an article implies familiarity with whatever the noun is.  An announcer or news reader would probably use the article.

> James River is polluted.

Comment: I think you are answering about something else